# AWS-CLI An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have hosted a nodejs Server AWS EC2 instance. My intention is to download(Copy) a zip file from my AWS S3 private Bucket(Please note I need S3 repo to be in private access). For my business requirement I must use shell command(aws-cli) in nodejs to copy zip file from S3 Bucket.

```
var executeShellCommand = require('child_process').exec,child;

executeShellCommand("aws s3 cp s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<ZIP_FILE_KEY>",
function (error, stdout, stderr){
if(error){
console.log(error);
}else{
console.log("ZIP file downloaded successfully");
}
});
```

When the shell command tries to execute, I am getting the following error:

```
{ Error: Command failed: aws s3 cp s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<ZIP_FILE_KEY> .
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'aws s3 cp s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<ZIP_FILE_KEY> .' }
```

When i try to run the cp command in EC2 instance command line it was working and the file was download too. Also I have found that  **aws_access_key_id** and **aws_secret_access_key** credentials should be know to bash command to access the private S3. Please correct me if I am wrong.

What configuration I am missing to make aws cp success via nodejs?

Comment: Show us the policy for your bucket and user, you moslt likely did not allow the HeadObject action

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa there is no `s3:HeadObject` action for policies.  `HEAD` is allowed by `s3:GetObject`.

Comment: @sqlbot that's interesting. I know there's `HeadBucket`, I just assumed a similar action would exist for Objects. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @vgokul129 Yes, the shell needs access to your credentials. From the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) > The AWS credentials file – located at ~/.aws/credentials on Linux, macOS, or Unix, or at C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\credentials on Windows. This file can contain multiple named profiles in addition to a default profile.